# Why does this code "print " nothing ? (c)

Tags: c

```
int i,*ip;
main()
{
    i=5;
    ip=&i;
    *ip=&ip,printf("%d",i);
}
```

Why does this code "prints" nothing ? it actually works and doesnt give an error.
edit : Actually this code prints something like 635435 which ,I think, may be the address of ip  but when ı use -pedantic-errors flag this give me an error so what should I say about the code ? this prints the address of ip or gives an error.

Comment: `*ip=&ip` is an error; if you don't see an error message then you need to change your compiler configuration.

Comment: There are others "errors" as well, for example plain `main()` is wrong. The `main` function is specified to always return an `int` and you need to provide that return type in the declaration of `main`.

Comment: Add `\n` after `%d` to see what gets printed.

Comment: It prints something for me. Of course, it could just as easily burn my house down. https://ideone.com/olegRe

Comment: Assignment `=` higher precedence than `,`, so `*ip=&ip` happens first and has the usual troubles (like "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]") of converting a pointer to an `int`.  @M.M is right.

Comment: @M.M and well when ı use flag ı take an error which ı can understand why it occurs  .Is not it default to be int if the the type of function is not specified ?    So can ı say this will create an error in context of ANSI C ? Because ıf ı dont use -pedantic-errors ı dont take any errors which confuses me .

Comment: You get an error because you are assigning a pointer value to an int (`*ip = &ip`). The int may not be large enough to hold that value. For example if `sizeof(ip) == 8` and `sizeof(i) == 4`. What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  actually I dont try anything with these code this is one of questions that my teacher suggested to solve but ı kinda got what it does , ı did  a mistake by not using the flag -pedantic-errors right ?

Comment: Check this answer: [Assigning an integer to a pointer](//stackoverflow.com/a/10489616). Assigning a pointer to an int is not recommended. I'm not sure what your teacher is trying to teach here. You could use a cast (`*ip = (int)&ip,printf("%d",i);` but what's the point? The value will (probably) be truncated. Maybe it is teaching you about operator precedence. `*ip = (&ip,printf("%d",i));` will give a different result, but makes, `&ip` pointless.

Comment: @M.M It's not an error, but it is worthy of a warning. If a compiler accepts conversions from pointers to integers (they nearly all do in practice, you probably have never used one that didn't), then they must accept this program. The C language does not distinguish between the implicit conversion in `*ip = &ip;` and an explicit conversion such as the cast `(int) &ip`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq the code violates the constraint 6.5.16.1/1  (which distinguishes `*ip = &ip` from `*ip = (int)&ip`)

Comment: @M.M Thanks for pointing out this clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `*ip=&ip` is not correct as first `*ip=&ip` is performed and `*ip` means `5` and that `5` got replaced with `address of ip`. It should be

```
ip = (int*)&ip;/* need to typecast as you are assigning address of pointer
                  to pointer variable which is not advisable */
```

your code looks like

```
int i,*ip;
int main(void) { /* side note use int main() instead of just main() */
        i=5;
        ip=&i;
        ip=(int*)&ip,printf("%d\n",i);

        return 0;
}
```

Also use `int main(void)` instead of just `main()` as C spec says

> It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local
>   to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```